# Apply Core Image Filter (CIBumpDistortion) to only one part of an image + change radius of selection and intensity of CIFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-image, cifilter

I would like to copy some of the features displayed here:

[image: Screenshot of an app]

So I would like the user to apply a CIBumpDistortion filter to an image and let him choose

1) where exactly he wants to apply it by letting him just touch the respective location on the image

2a) the size of the circle selection (first slider in the image above)

2b) the intensity of the CIBumpDistortion Filter (second slider in the image above)

I read some previously asked questions, but they were not really helpful and some of the solutions sounded really far from userfriendly (e.g. cropping the needed part, then reapplying it to the old image). Hope I am not asking for too much at once. Objective-C would be preferred, but any help/hint would be much appreciated really! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a demo (iPad) project that lets you apply most supported CIFilters. It interrogates each filter for the parameters it needs and has built-in support for float values as well as points and colors. For the bump distortion filter it lets you select a center point, a radius, and an input scale.

The project is called CIFilterTest. You can download the project from Github at this link: https://github.com/DuncanMC/CIFilterTest

There is quite a bit of housekeeping in the app to support the general-purpose ability to use any supported filter, but it should give you enough information to implement your own bump filter as you're asking to do.

The approach I worked out to applying a filter and getting it to render without extending outside of the bounds of the original image is to first apply a clamp filter to the image (`CIAffineClamp`) set to the identity transform, take the output of that filter and feed that into the input of your "target" filter (the bump distortion filter in this case) and then take the output of that and feed that into a crop filter (`CICrop`) with the bounds of the crop filter set to the original image size.

The method to look for in the sample project is called `showImage`, in `ViewController.m`

Comment: Thank you a lot for you answer and the Github project you created and pointed me to, both is highly appreciated! 

(Downvote must have been someone else)

Comment: I wish people would post a constructive criticism when they down-vote. I'm fine if somebody thinks my answer is bad, but I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> 1) where exactly he wants to apply it by letting him just touch the
>   respective location on the image
>
> 2a) the size of the circle selection (first slider in the image above)
>
> 2b) the intensity of the CIBumpDistortion Filter (second slider in the
>   image above)

Well, `CIBumpDistortion` has those attributes:

- `inputCenter` is the center of the effect
- `inputRadius` is the size of the circle selection
- `inputScale` is the intensity

Simon

Answer (score 1):

To show the bump:
You have to pass the location (kCIInputCenterKey) on image with Radius Size (white Circle in your case)

```
func appleBumpDistort(toImage currentImage: UIImage, radius : Float, intensity: Float) -> UIImage? {
    var context: CIContext = CIContext()
    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortion")    
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: currentImage)
    currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)


    currentFilter.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    currentFilter.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
    currentFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: currentImage.size.width / 2, y: currentImage.size.height / 2), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)

    guard let image = currentFilter.outputImage else { return nil }

    if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent) {
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
        return processedImage
    }
    return nil
}
```